# Crystal Report Shared NumberVar from sub-report to main-report. Why first record display 0 value?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to get Shared NumberVar from Sub-Report to Main-Report but **first record display 0 value** in this Group footer (My value display on Group footer) **value do not match in same line**

I need to display correct value in same line.

**Please help.**

**Sub-Report**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar qty;
qty:= sum({OE.QTYSOLD});
```

**Main-Report**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar qty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main report formula getting a subreport shared variable value must be in a section BELOW the subreport section.  This is because section formulas are evaluated before subreports in the same section.

So split the section or move the subreport to a higher section.

Comment: Can i force a Subreport to execute automatically before the main Report ?

Comment: no.  But you can use other tactics, such as creating SQL Expressions or using a function from a UFL (User Function Library) to retrieve data.